# Why can't I specify the storage class for formal parameters of a function?

Tags: c, function, formal-languages, storage-class-specifier

When I do as below the code works fine :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test( int a)
{
 printf("a=%d\n",a);   
}

int main()
{
    test(10);
    return 1;
}
```

But when I do

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test( auto int a) // Or static int a Or extern int a
{
 printf("a=%d\n",a);   
}

int main()
{
    test(10);
    return 1;
}
```

It generates an error,

> error: storage class specified for parameter 'a'

Why is that error? What happens internally(memory management)?

But it works fine without any error when I do:

```
void test( register int a)
{
 printf("a=%d\n",a);   
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: How could a parameter be `static`? It would change with every call to the function anyway... And it definitely can't be `extern`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First,quoting `C11`, chapter 6.7.6.3

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is `register`.

So, this is *explicitly* specified in the standard.

That said, this restriction exists because with an explicit storage class like `static`/ `extern`, there will be problems in memory management, as function parameters are in the block scope for the function and their lifetimes are limited to the execution of the function body.

- A parameter variable cannot outlive the call to the function; otherwise, what would be the effect of the argument in the next call to the same function? So `static` storage is not meaningful, and `auto` is redundant.
- Since the function parameters has no linkage, `extern` also makes no sense.

---

Additionally, as mentioned in `C11`, for a hosted environment, the conforming signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`, at least.

Comment: OK, I took advantage of your invitation. Hope it's ok with you.

Comment: @rici More than okay sir, thanks for the contribution, as always. :)

Comment: Very nice answer, with explaining the rationale.:-)