# What is The Default Storage class in Formal parameters

Tags: c

Is it necessary for a variable to have a storage class in c ? if yes then
what is the default storage class for a variable in formal argument in c i.e int foo (int x) so just before int x is there by default any storage class already assign to it (i.e register which is only possible storage class in c for formal arguments ) or no storage class assign ? and if register class is assign by default then what would happen if the variable size exceeds the size of register will it be converted into auto??

Comment: How many storage classes are there in C? Can you name them? And eliminate the obviously wrong ones?

Comment: there are only 4 storage class in c you may go to [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-classes-in-c/)

Comment: That page should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: it tells that by default if no storage class is declared then compiler assign auto to local variable and extern to global variable but it can't tell about storage class in formal argument

Comment: Function parameters have `auto` storage duration - [C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.9.1/9.

Comment: `register` does not mean "CPU register". This is gone since the 1980ies.

Comment: @JohnBode And that would be the answer.  I was still reading [6.7.6.3 Function declarators](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.1p9).  Not sure why this question is getting so many downvotes.  It's actually an interesting question about C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameters have `auto` storage class.

> **6.9.1 Function definitions**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> ...
> 5 If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the declaration of each parameter shall
> include an identifier, except for the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single
> parameter of type **`void`**, in which case there shall not be an identifier. No declaration list
> shall follow.
> 6 If the declarator includes an identifier list, each declaration in the declaration list shall
> have at least one declarator, those declarators shall declare only identifiers from the
> identifier list, and every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared. An identifier
> declared as a typedef name shall not be redeclared as a parameter. The declarations in the
> declaration list shall contain no storage-class specifier other than **`register`** and no
> initializations.
>
> **Semantics**
> ...
> 9 Each parameter has automatic storage duration; its identifier is an lvalue.<sup>164)</sup> The layout
> of the storage for parameters is unspecified.
> ...
>
> ---
>
> <sup>164) A parameter identifier cannot be redeclared in the function body except in an enclosed block.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

There's actually a bit to unpack here.  First, remember that C allows two styles of function definitions.  The 1989 standard introduced what's called prototype syntax, where both parameter names and their types are specified in the argument list:

```
void foo( int bar, double bletch )
{
  // body of foo
}
```

Clause 5 refers to this style of function definition.

There's also the older (and no longer recommended) K&R style of function definition, where the argument list only contains the identifiers, with a separate set of declarations before the function body:

```
foo( bar, bletch ) // K&R didn't have the void datatype, use implicit int
  int bar;
  double bletch;
{
  // body of foo
}
```

Clause 6 refers to this style of definition.

Per clause 9, function parameters have `auto` storage class; however, per clause 6, you *may* use `register` storage class for parameters declared using K&R syntax:

```
foo( bar, bletch )
  register int bar;
  double bletch;
{
  ...
}
```

But since this style of function definition is no longer recommended (prototype syntax allows the compiler to check for agreement of parameters between function calls and function definitions, and it's also just plain easier to read), you really don't have to worry about it.

Note that the `register` keyword is largely vestigial, and dates from a time when C compilers weren't all that good at optimization.  About the only practical effect of using it with modern compilers is that you won't be able to take the address of the thing you declared with it.

**EDIT**

Missed this critical bit:

> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> ...
> 2 The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is **`register`**.

Unless you use the `register` keyword in a parameter declaration, a function parameter will have `auto` storage duration - there is no need to explicitly write `auto` (and, per the clause above, isn't allowed anyway).

Comment: thanks now i got it,but one thing does it mean if i write auto in formal argument the compiler shows error but when i will not specify the storage class the compiler would by default make it automatic storage??    compiler output  [link](https://ideone.com/X9M3U4)

Comment: @senti143: See my edit.  The only storage class you may specify in a function parameter declaration is `register`; otherwise, function parameters have `auto` storage duration.

Answer (score 1):

Per C 2018 6.2.4 5:

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier **static** has *automatic storage duration*,…

Per 6.2.2 6, a function parameter has no linkage:

> The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than an object or a function; an identifier declared to be a function parameter; a block scope identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier **extern**.

Per 6.7.6.3 2, a function parameter cannot be declared with `static`:

> The only storage-class specifier that shall occur in a parameter declaration is **register**.

So a function parameter has no linkage and is not declared with `static`, and therefore it has automatic storage duration.

Regarding your question “Is it necessary for a variable to have a storage class in c?”, a variable consists of an object (a region of storage that can represent values) and an identifier (a name). Objects necessarily have storage durations, per 6.2.4 1:

> An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary for a variable to have a storage class in c?

Yes

> if yes then what is the default storage class for a variable in formal argument in c i.e int foo (int x)

auto

Comment: check it once[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439073/why-cant-i-specify-the-storage-class-for-formal-parameters-of-a-function)